# Position fixed not working in md-sidenav-container (Material 2)

Tags: angular-material2

Position:fixed inside the md-sidenav-container not working

Solution :

md-sidenav-container has transform : 3d(0,0,0) thats why position fixed not working.. for that we should make the transform to none then position fixed of element will be work..

Use the follwing css then position fixed will be work on element.

```
   .mat-sidenav-container,
     md-sidenav-container div[style],
     .mat-sidenav-content{
           transform: none !important;
           -webkit-transform: none !important;
      }
```

Comment: Please click `<>` and post a [mcve]

Comment: Your button is now 100% of the screen.  That is likely not right?